# How to get the format and full range of an Excel sheet to HTML email body?

Tags: html, excel, vba, email, gmail

I've automated an Excel file to generate an email with the data in a particular range of the file.

It all works but the email doesn't display the full range. Instead it shows the part of the range and then provides a link to view the full message. When I click that "View entire message" the formatting doesn't appear as per the Excel sheet.

I'm using below VBA code. Is there a way I can use more formatting options? (I want this for Gmail not Outlook)

```
On Error Resume Next
   ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add( _
   SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
   Filename:=File1, _
   Sheet:=rng.Worksheet.Name, _
   Source:=rng.Address, _
   HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic).Publish
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for gmail. The link seems to be for outlook. I updated my question now.